# is it possible to change number of rows or fontsize of datepicker in titanium appcelerator?

Tags: uiview, titanium, uicomponents, appcelerator-mobile

if so how?

```
birthday_picker = Ti.UI.createPicker({
    type:Ti.UI.PICKER_TYPE_DATE,
    minDate:minDate,
    maxDate:maxDate,
    value: new Date(),
    top:200
});
```

Answer (score 0):

if  you create a custom picker, you can change whatever you like.

i would suggest downloading the KitchenSink examples from Appcelerator, I know there is a picker.js that should get you headed in the right direction

http://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides/Getting+Started+with+Kitchen+Sink

Answer (score 0):

the picker with

```
type:Ti.UI.PICKER_TYPE_DATE,
```

is not editable. if just want to change the localization, since the english style is wrong, you need to change the info.plist generated into you build path. you should change the entry **Localization native development region** from English into your prefered localization and then build and run you app within xcode again. have a try.